# Regex pattern for an xml file using vbscript

Tags: regex, xml, vbscript

Hi I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Execution><MODULE Name="Billing Payments" StartTime="2:45:31 PM" EndTime="2:45:39 PM"><TESTCASE Name="BP01_One_Time_Payment" StartTime="2:45:31 PM" EndTime="2:45:36 PM"><ITERATION ID="1" StartTime="2:45:31 PM" EndTime="2:45:34 PM"><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 1" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 1" ScreenshotPath=""></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 2" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 2" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_1"></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="FAIL" StepName="Test Step Failed 1" StepDetails="Test Step Details Failed 1" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_2"/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 1" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 1" ScreenshotPath=""/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 2" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 2" ScreenshotPath=""/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 3" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 3" ScreenshotPath=""/><SCREENSHOT Status="Screenshot" StepName="Screenshot for Navigation" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_5"></SCREENSHOT><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 3" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 3" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_3"></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="FAIL" StepName="Test Step Failed 2" StepDetails="Test Step Details Failed 1" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_4"/><STEPRESULT Status="TERMINATE" StepName="Execution for the current iteration terminated due to failure in above step" StepDetails="Test Step Details Failed 1" ScreenshotPath=""/></ITERATION><ITERATION ID="2" StartTime="2:45:34 PM" EndTime="2:45:36 PM"><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 1" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 1" ScreenshotPath=""></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 2" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 2" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_6"></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="FAIL" StepName="Test Step Failed 1" StepDetails="Test Step Details Failed 1" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_7"/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 1" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 1" ScreenshotPath=""/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 2" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 2" ScreenshotPath=""/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 3" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 3" ScreenshotPath=""/><SCREENSHOT Status="Screenshot" StepName="Screenshot for Navigation" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_8"></SCREENSHOT><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 2" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 3" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_9"></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="FAIL" StepName="Test Step Failed 2" StepDetails="Test Step Details Failed 1" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_10"/></ITERATION></TESTCASE><TESTCASE Name="BP02_Enroll_Paperless" StartTime="2:45:36 PM" EndTime="2:45:39 PM"><ITERATION ID="1" StartTime="2:45:36 PM" EndTime="2:45:39 PM"><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 4" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 4" ScreenshotPath=""></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 5" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 5" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_11"></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="FAIL" StepName="Test Step Failed 3" StepDetails="Test Step Details Failed 3" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_12"/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 4" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 4" ScreenshotPath=""/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 5" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 5" ScreenshotPath=""/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 6" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 6" ScreenshotPath=""/><SCREENSHOT Status="Screenshot" StepName="Screenshot for Navigation" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_15"></SCREENSHOT><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 3" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 3" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_13"></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="FAIL" StepName="Test Step Failed 4" StepDetails="Test Step Details Failed 4" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_14"/></ITERATION></TESTCASE></MODULE><MODULE Name="Profile Management" StartTime="2:45:40 PM" EndTime="2:45:43 PM"><TESTCASE Name="PM01_Forgot_Username" StartTime="2:45:40 PM" EndTime="2:45:41 PM"><ITERATION ID="1" StartTime="2:45:40 PM" EndTime="2:45:41 PM"><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 6" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 6" ScreenshotPath=""></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 7" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 7" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_16"></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="FAIL" StepName="Test Step Done 5" StepDetails="Test Step Details Failed 5" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_17"/></ITERATION></TESTCASE><TESTCASE Name="PM02_Edit_Profile" StartTime="2:45:41 PM" EndTime="2:45:43 PM"><ITERATION ID="1" StartTime="2:45:42 PM" EndTime="2:45:43 PM"><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 8" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 6" ScreenshotPath=""></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="PASS" StepName="Test Step Pass 9" StepDetails="Test Step Details Pass 7" ScreenshotPath="ScreenShot_Path_16"></STEPRESULT><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 8" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 8" ScreenshotPath=""/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 9" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 9" ScreenshotPath=""/><STEPRESULT Status="DONE" StepName="Test Step Done 10" StepDetails="Test Step Details Done 10" ScreenshotPath=""/></ITERATION></TESTCASE></MODULE></Execution>
```

Please suggest as to how the regex pattern should be created using vbscript to match the above xml format ? Please help I am new to this

I have tried

```
Set re = New RegExp
 With re.Pattern    = "'var xmlData = <Execution>[\s\S]*?<\/Execution>'"
 Regex.IgnoreCase = True 
 Regex.Global = True

  End With
```

Please tell me where I ahave gone wrong ? It gives me the error Object required:false .

Comment: "Please tell me where I ahave gone wrong?" — You are trying to use a regular expression instead of an XML parser.

Comment: I have a local xml file which I want to load it into a html file which is in the same local file since I am not able to load it I am trying different ways to do the same. I know I might be entirely wrong as well. Please find the question here which I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717290/replacing-specific-ines-of-an-html-file-with-different-lines-using-vbscript/28719321#28719321

Comment: You've seen this post, I hope? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

For context see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28717290/603855).

The specific problem:

`With` needs an object; so change

```
Set re = New RegExp
With re.Pattern    = "'var xmlData = <Execution>[\s\S]*?<\/Execution>'"
Regex.IgnoreCase = True
```

to

```
Set re = New RegExp
With re
   .Pattern    = "'var xmlData = <Execution>[\s\S]*?<\/Execution>'"
   .IgnoreCase = True
```

Getting the syntax right won't solve the real problem. You need to replace  the x in `var xmlData = 'x';` **reliably** without breaking the Javascript rules (e.g. EOL markers in the .XML to insert will break the code).

An XML parser won't help, because the OT needs to manipulate Javascript code embedded into .HTML.